# How to make a dice roller remove the last rolled race in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using a dice rolling script to roll through different faces of my classmates as a sort of wheel of fortune system and I'm completely new to both unity and C#. I've done some googling and come up with the following code that works.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class Dice : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Array of dice sides sprites to load from Resources folder
    public Sprite[] diceSides;

    // Reference to sprite renderer to change sprites
    private SpriteRenderer rend;

    // Use this for initialization
    private void Start()
    {
        // Assign Renderer component
        rend = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

        // Load dice sides sprites to array from DiceSides subfolder of Resources folder
        diceSides = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("DiceSides/");   
    }

    // If you left click over the dice then RollTheDice coroutine is started
    public void OnMouseDown()
    {
        StartCoroutine("RollTheDice");
    }

    // Coroutine that rolls the dice
    private IEnumerator RollTheDice()
    {
        // Variable to contain random dice side number.
        // It needs to be assigned. Let it be 0 initially
        int randomDiceSide = 0;

        // Final side or value that dice reads in the end of coroutine
        int finalSide = 0;

        // Loop to switch dice sides ramdomly
        // before final side appears. 20 iterations here.
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
        {
            // Pick up random value from 0 to 5 (All inclusive)
            randomDiceSide = Random.Range(0, 9);

            // Set sprite to upper face of dice from array according to random value
            rend.sprite = diceSides[randomDiceSide];

            diceSides = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("DiceSides/");

            // Pause before next iteration
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);
        }

        // Assigning final side so you can use this value later in your game
        // for player movement for example
        finalSide = randomDiceSide;

        // Show final dice value in Console
        Debug.Log(finalSide);
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to make it so that when someone's face is selected they are taken out of the array. I don't really know how to do it. If you need any more details to help me out feel free to ask. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top, add this using statement: `using System.Collections.Generic;`

Have a `private List<Sprite> finalSideSprites` variable.

In `Start`:  `finalSideSprites = new List<Sprite>(Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("DiceSides/"));`

In `RollTheDice`: Replace `finalSide = randomDiceSide;` with

```
finalSide = (int)Random.Range(0, finalSideSprites.Count - 1);
rend.sprite = finalSideSprites[finalSide];
finalSideSprites.RemoveAt(finalSide);
if(finalSideSprites.Count <= 0){
    finalSideSprites = new List<Sprite>(Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("DiceSides/"));
}
```

Essentially, this keeps a list of eligible "final side" values, picks one at random, removes it from the eligible values list, then resets the list when they've all been used.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did what you asked however it isn't removing them still. In the console i'm getting the following message, '''ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index'''

Comment: Ah, whoops, off by one error. I've updated the answer. Should be `finalSide = (int)Random.Range(0, finalSideSprites.Count - 1);`

Comment: It doesn't look like anything has changed. Do i replace the 'finalSide = (int)Random.Range(0, finalSideSprites.Count - 1);' with 'finalSide = (int)Random.Range(0, finalSideSprites.Count - 1);'? I'm still getting the same error message after doing that.

Comment: This is what it is currently looking like:

 `finalSide = (int)Random.Range(0, finalSideSprites.Count - 1);
        rend.sprite = finalSideSprites[finalSide];
        finalSideSprites.RemoveAt(finalSide);
        if (finalSideSprites.Count == 0)
        {
            finalSideSprites = new List<Sprite>(Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("DiceSides/"));
        }`

Comment: Works on my end. Maybe you forgot to copy this into Start? `finalSideSprites = new List<Sprite>(Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("DiceSides/"));` If not, try adding `Debug.Log("FinalSidesAvailable" + finalSideSprites.Count)` and see what that value is? Should be the same as the number of dice sides you have.

Comment: Ah seems like that was the problem. It seems to be working although I got a tad confused for the first second just then as it still cycles through the used faces despite not coming up lol. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Ah, yeah, wasn't sure exactly how many faces you had so I thought it would be fine to cycle through them so that you wouldn't run out :) If you're good with this, approve my answer?

Comment: Yeah thank you. The truth is I don't know how many more sides i'll need since I don't have everyone's pictures yet. But this works fine for what I need to do thank you for your help.

Comment: You should do `finalSideSprites = new List<Sprite>(Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("DiceSides/"));` only **once** and rather work on a copy of that original list: `List<Sprite> workingCopy;` and `workingCopy = new List<Sprite>(finalSideSprites);`

Comment: Well, really for efficiency we should do `finalSideSprites = new List<Sprite>(diceSides);` but I was trying to adhere to the existing code reloading it every time in case the data source is somehow being altered during runtime, but you're right -- it probably isn't.